# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar valor dentro de un Array en Mongo?

Tags: nodejs, api, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo el siguiente documento almacenado en Mongo:

```
{
    "Estado": 1,
    "_id": "5e1df384a096622edc29fa3d",
    "empresas": "5dfbeec1f87e0e3030b38143",
    "Codigo": "1001AZXL001",
    "Codigo_Barras": "00000",
    "Descripcion": "Medias",
    "Detalles": [
        {
            "_id": "5e1df384a096622edc29fa3f",
            "bodegas": "5e138df1b4e8b40554c2d28a",
            "Cantidad": 6,
            "Cantidad_Reservada": 0,
            "Precio": 150000,
            "Unidad_Medida": "UND"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e1df384a096622edc29fa3e",
            "bodegas": "5e189ba83d837209005527d9",
            "Cantidad": 15,
            "Cantidad_Reservada": 0,
            "Precio": 150000,
            "Unidad_Medida": "UND"
        }
    ],
    "Talla": "XL",
    "Color": "AZ",
    "Minimo": 5000,
    "Maximo": 30000,
    "Fecha_Creacion": "2020-01-14T16:59:48.994Z"
}
```

Estoy usando Mongoose para realizar el CRUD desde Nodejs, pero tengo un problema al momento de tratar de actualizar alguno de los objetos contenidos dentro de **"Detalles"**. Si solo necesito actualizar del objeto con id **5e1df384a096622edc29fa3f**, el campo de **Cantidad_Reservada**, no estoy seguro de como puedo acceder a ese campo.

Desde Nodejs estoy actualizando el campo de la siguiente manera:

```
  update: async (req,res,next) => {
        try {
            console.log(req.body._id)
            console.log(req.body.Cantidad_Reservada)
         //   const reg = await models.Producto.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.body._id},{Codigo_Barras:req.body.Cantidad_Reservada});
            const reg = await models.Producto.where({ _id: req.body._id }).where({ _id: req.body._id_Producto }).update({ $set: {Cantidad_Reservada: 'words' }})
            res.status(200).json(reg);
        } catch(e){
            res.status(500).send({
                message:'Ocurrió un error'
            });
            next(e);
        }
    }
```

Y estos son los parametros que estoy enviando desde Postman, pero debo necesitar también el _id del objeto que quiero actualizar dentro de detalles.

```
{
    "_id": "5e1df384a096622edc29fa3d",
    "_id_Producto" : "5e1df384a096622edc29fa3f",
    "Cantidad_Reservada": "10"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te compliques tanto. Gracias a Dios `mongoose` tiene la capacidad de detectar donde ha habido cambios en nuestro documento y puede aplicar solo aquello que modificamos de manera muy sencilla.

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera.

```
//Mi modelo declarado. 

const Producto = require('donde/esta/mi/modelo')//Es similar a lo que tu haces



//...Dentro del request...

const datos = req.body // Suponiendo que uses json parse

Producto
.findById(req.body._id)
.exec()
.then(producto=>{

  if(!producto) throw 'No existe el producto'

  producto.Detalles.id(req.body._id_Producto).Cantidad_Reservada = req.body.Cantidad_Reservada

  return producto.save()


}).then(productoGuardado => {

   return res.json(productoGuardado).send()

}).catch(//...Capturas los errores)
```